# Find the answer to an series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, special-functions

I've been stuck with calculating the close form of series of the following problem.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\ln(k)-\ln(x+k)+\frac{x}{k}\right)
\end{align*}

for ‎real ‎constant $x\geq1$.

My solution: We have

\begin{align*}
S_n &=\sum_{k=1}^n \Big(\ln k - \ln (k+x)+\frac{x}{n}\Big) =xH_n+\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\frac{k}{k+x}\\ &=x(\gamma+\psi_0(n+1))+\ln\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k+x}=x\gamma+x\psi_0(n+1)+\ln\frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+n)}
\end{align*}
my question:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}S_n=?$

Also, I know that $\Gamma(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\frac{n!n^x}{x(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+n)}$ and so $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\frac{n!n^x}{(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+n)}$, but I can not $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}S_n$ solve. Can you help me?‎‎

Comment: Could you show your attempt - what method you have tried?

Comment: Svyatoslav. I know that, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n ln\frac{k}{k+x}+\frac{x}{k}=xH_n+\log((1)_n)-\log((1+x)_n)$, where $H_n$ is Harmonic Number and $(a)_n$ is Pochhammer Symbol, but i cannot calculate the series value.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. If you add some context to the problem description, the problem can be reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use another approach to get the answer.

Using the Frullani integral $\,\displaystyle \ln x=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-xt}}tdt\,$ and the fact that $\,\displaystyle\frac1k=\int_0^\infty e^{-kt}dt$
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-kt}}t-\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(k+x)t}}t+xe^{-kt}\right)dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-kt}}t\left(e^{-tx}+xt-1\right)dt$$
Changing the order of summation and integration and performing summation,
$$S(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-tx}+xt-1}t\frac{dt}{e^t-1}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}S(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{e^t-1}dt\overset{s=e^{-t}}{=}\int_0^1\frac{1-s^x}{1-s}ds=\psi_0(1+x)+\gamma$$
$$\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,S(x)=\gamma x+\ln\Gamma(1+x)+C$$
Taking $x=0\,\,f(0)=0\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,C=0$
$$S(x)=\gamma x+\ln\Gamma(1+x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Computing the partial sum$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\log(k)-\log(x+k)+\frac{x}{k}\right)$$ Using Pochhamer symbols
$$S_n=x H_n+\log \left(\frac{(1)_n}{(x+1)_n}\right)$$
Converting them asgamma function
$$S_n=x H_n+\log (\Gamma (x+1))+\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (n+x+1)}\right)$$

Using the asymptotic of harmonic numbers, Stirling approximation twice and finishing with Taylor series
$$S_n=\gamma x+\log (\Gamma (x+1))-\frac {x^2}{2n}\left(1-\frac{2 x+3}{6 n}+\frac{(x+1)^2}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

The same could be obtained using Euler-MacLaurin summation formula since
$$\int_{1}^{n}\left(\log(k)-\log(x+k)+\frac{x}{k}\right)\,dk=$$
$$(n+x) \log (n)-(n+x) \log (n+x)+(x+1) \log (x+1)$$